# Causing a Tkinter widget to change based on input from another widget

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have created a simple command-line game and am considering porting it to GUI. This way I would be able to give the player the option to make choices through clicking buttons, instead of being forced to type in text.

My problem is that it would be tricky to do without the ability to change the text on Label and Button widgets, so how might one go about properly doing this?

Here is what I have so far (after laurencevs's answer):

```
def goAway(event):
    label02.configure(text = " ")
    label01.configure(text = "Go away")
    time.sleep(1)
    label01.configure(text = "GO AWAY.")
    time.sleep(1)
    label01.configure(text = "Seriously, go AWAY!")
    time.sleep(1)
    label01.configure(text = "That's it.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    quit("GOODBYE.")

button01 = Button(root, text="Click me, see what happens.")
button01.grid(row=1001, column=1001)
button01.bind("<Button-1>", goAway)
```

But all it does is wait 3 seconds and then close the program. How can I fix this

The idea is that when clicked the button will change the text in the Label `label01` to "Go away", wait one second, change the text to "GO AWAY.", etc. and then quit, printing "GOODBYE" to users running it in a terminal.

Comment: Go to [Effbot's site on `tkinter`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/). Learn it. Love it. [NMT's site](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) is darn good, too.

Comment: [Unpythonic.net](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/FrontPage) has some good info too (I occasionally refer to the page on `tkFileDialog`).

Comment: Unfortunately, requests for tutorials or other resources are off-topic for SO, so I'll be leaving it as a comment. I just couldn't resist making a plug for Effbot. :P

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I never asked for a tutorial, I just want a bit of code I can add to my program that makes it do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely can change the text on a Label or a Button.

All you have to do is use the `Label.configure()` method. Say you want to change the text in `label1` to "Don't Panic", you just do this:

```
label1.configure(text = "Don't Panic")
```

The same goes for buttons and other widgets.

If you want to create a Button that does this when it is clicked, you must define a function which changes the label's text, and then use the function's name (for example `foo`) when creating the Button like this:

```
button = Button(window, text = "I am a button", command = foo)
```

The full code for that would look like this:

```
from tkinter import * # Tkinter in Python 2

def foo():
    label1.configure(text = "Don't Panic")

window = Tk()
# other (optional) window setup here

label1 = Label(window, text = "")
button = Button(window, text = "I am a button", command = foo)

# pack the label and button and initiate the window's mainloop here
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I do this for buttons?

Comment: With buttons you can just do the same, i.e. `button.configure(text = "New button text")`

Comment: Actually, it's `Label.configure(text="This is text")` not `Label.configure(text = "This is text")` Figured this out on my own :D